# How to initialize a variable whose value is retrieved from nextval

Tags: sql, oracle

I planned to insert one order into `order` table:

```
insert into order(id) value (seq.nextval);
```

Assume the generated order id is 2, correspondingly several order items need to be inserted into the `orderitem` table:

```
insert into orderitem(productid, orderid) values (1, 2);
insert into orderitem(productid, orderid) values (3, 2);
```

I tried to execute all the above in one sql script:

```
DEFINE oid = seq.nextval;
insert into order(id) value (&oid);
insert into orderitem(productid, orderid) values (1, &oid);
insert into orderitem(productid, orderid) values (3, &oid);
```

But the execution failed because the *variable* `oid` is just a placeholder, meaning in each `insert` the `seq.nextval` will be executed in any case. As a result, the insert of order item records into `orderitem` failed

Anyone knows how to resolve the repeating execution of `seq.nextval`?

Comment: Use [INSERT ... RETURNING](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause). And column `orderid` in table `orderitem` should be a foreign key to table `order`.

Comment: @Rui and ? Was any of this answer helpful ? Would be nice to have a feedback...

Comment: @VBoka Sorry for late reply. It was actually a bit difficult for me to choose among these three answers. But after long consideration, I voted for your answer, as that is more pure SQL. Thanks a lot for your help (Y) Moreover, I got to know that sequence have currval function

Comment: I am happy to help and I am sure others are too. I am happy to hear you have learned something new from this. Also I would like to note to you that if this is true: "It was actually a bit difficult for me to choose among these three answers" that means that all of this three answers are of some help so they are useful. I believe you can give them vote up because tomorrow to someone else, maybe some other answer will be better than mine. I repeat: I suggest to vote up all three answers if they are useful. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will find this helpful :

```
select seq.nextval into oid from dual;
insert into "order"(id) values (&oid);
insert into orderitem(productid, orderid) values (1, seq.currval);
insert into orderitem(productid, orderid) values (3, seq.currval);
```

In this example you will insert into the table "order" new value and in table orderitem that same value. I have created script `SEQS.SQL` having just that and it worked when I have run it in SQL PLUS.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

P.S. this will also work:

```
DEFINE oid = seq.nextval;
insert into "order"(id) values (&oid);
insert into orderitem(productid, orderid) values (1, seq.currval);
insert into orderitem(productid, orderid) values (3, seq.currval);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use PL/SQL block then it will be quite easier.

> ```
> Declare
> Oid number;
> Begin
>
> Oid := seq.nextval;
>
> insert into order(id) value (oid);
> insert into orderitem(productid, orderid) values (1, oid);
> insert into orderitem(productid, orderid) values (3, oid);
>
> End;
> /
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi @Tajesh you have a misspell value > values. But I believe this will not help him. What OP wants, I think, is to enter oid = 1, then oid = 1 and again oid = 1 for every insert statement. Maybe I am wrong  :) Also, I am always getting error when I do not put order key word under "" ?

Comment: Nope. This solution will insert same number for 3 inserts. And yes inserts are copy pasted from question so spelling also. :)

Comment: You are correct. Sorry, did try this in a similar but not the same way and immediately thought that it was wrong... VOTE UP. DEMO: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=74e9d4a91768b259b7d6ce1da46c91aa

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do it in one SQL statement,

```
insert all
    into orders(id) values (seq.nextval)
    into orderitems(orderid,productid) values (seq.nextval, 1)
    into orderitems(orderid,productid) values (seq.nextval, 3)
select * from dual;
```

Sequence values are incremented only once in a multi-table insert, which can be confusing, but it seems to do what you need in this case.

Normally though, you would do this in PL/SQL by assigning the new `id` value to a variable, either explicitly setting `some_variable := seq.nextval` or by using a `returning` clause for the insert into `orders` to capture the new value (this is more generic as it handles values assigned in triggers and identity columns).

Comment: does this `insert all` correspond to SQL standard?

Comment: @Rui I doubt it, although it’s not highlighted as a violation by `set flagger full` / `alter session set flagger = full`.

Comment: I don't think `seq.nextval` is ANSI Standard either.